# Pydantic preparing data for validation

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

```
class CampaignData(BaseModel):
    title: NonEmptyString
    conversion: Conversion
    date: datetime.date
    name: NonEmptyString
    budget: PositiveDecimal


    @validator('date', pre=True)
    def format_date(cls, value: str) -> datetime.date:
        #some logic
            
            
    @validator('name')
    def check_name(cls, value: str) -> str:
        #some logic

        return value
        
        
    @root_validator
    def check_value_params_match(cls, values):
        #some logic

        return values
```

Incoming data example

```
{'campaigns': {'title': 'HS_GP', 'conversion': 'Buyer14', 'date': '22.04.21', 'name': 'HS_GP_UAC', 'budget': '2000'}}
```

How can I make input data be converted before `@validator` and `@root_validator` work, so that the `value` argument in all validators gets rid of the `campaigns` key?

```
{'title': 'HS_GP', 'conversion': 'Buyer14', 'date': '22.04.21', 'name': 'HS_GP_UAC', 'budget': '2000'}
```

Some thind like the function `remove_key` should be called at the very beginning

```
def remove_key(data):
    return data['campaigns']
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to use the data that is *inside* `campaigns`.

The following should work:

```py
data = {
    'campaigns': {
        'title': 'HS_GP',
        'conversion': 'Buyer14',
        'date': '22.04.21',
        'name':
        'HS_GP_UAC',
        'budget': '2000'
    }
}


class CampaignData(BaseModel):
    title: NonEmptyString
    conversion: Conversion
    date: datetime.date
    name: NonEmptyString
    budget: PositiveDecimal

    @validator('date', pre=True)
    def format_date(cls, value: str) -> datetime.date:
        #some logic

    # etc...

campaign_data = CampaignData.parse_obj(data['campaigns'])
```

Comment: That doesn't really seem to be what I'm asking. I don't mean to refer to object attributes with a point, I mean that inside each validation method, only values will be input, without `campaigns` key

Comment: In other words, is there a way to pre-prepare the data before calling the validation methods. What is done at the very beginning. I.e. I can do value = value['campaigns'] in each validation method, but it has to be done in each method. Is it possible to do this for all methods at once?